# Azure Table Service - 409 errors all over the place

Tags: azure, uuid

On the last 4 hours i've got 200+ requests failing on azure table reporting `409`. I've looked around and this means PK duplication. Since this is a table specific for logging, I really don't care about the keys so my `RowKey` is `Guid.NewGuid()`...

Is there another reason for azure table to return a `409` or I'm actually seeing UUIDs colliding?

PS: i really hope that there's another reason, because on the last 4 hours I've handled only 50k requests...

Comment: According to (this)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Table-Service-Error-Codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN] it can be 2 other things: TableBeingDeleted or TableAlreadyExists

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your client didn't see the HTTP 200 response indicating a successful insertion (client timeout, network error, etc), but the insert did successfully happen on the server side.  Then when the client retried the operation it received a 409 since the entity already existed on the server.

You will be able to see evidence of this in the storage analytics logs if you turn those on.

You can try to troubleshoot the initial client failure, but that doesn't ultimately solve the problem since you need to handle this type of failure anyways.  Since you are just writing logging data then you probably don't care about the 409 on the retry so the best solution is to just ignore it.  Other possible solutions are to use the 'Insert Or Replace' or 'Insert Or Merge' operations instead of just an Insert.

For some more context see https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/35 or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9ab80192-6450-41c2-a964-4ea092c1f6ef/table-storage-handling-retry-error-where-item-already-exists?forum=windowsazuredata.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `Guid.NewGuid()` quicker than the clock, it may generate the same Guid. Try putting a few milliseconds between `Guid.NewGuid()` calls.